# change R,G,B of image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, colors

I want to change R,G,B color of Image using jquery. I am converting image to canvas but it's not working Please fix my error or what am I missing.

This time I am just changing Red color if this works rest can be done same.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function redSwitch() {

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var photo = new Image();
        photo.src = $('#pic').attr('src');

        canvas.width = photo.width;
        canvas.height = photo.height; 
        ctx.drawImage(photo, 0, 0); 
        var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var val = $('#red').val();

        for(var y=0; y<imgPixels.height; y++)
        {
            for(var x=0; x<imgPixels.width; x++)
            {
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                if(imgPixels.data[i]+val > 255)
                {
                    imgPixels.data[i] = 255;
                }
                else
                {
                    imgPixels.data[i] = imgPixels.data[i]+val;
                }
            }
        }

    }


    $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#red').change(function(){
        redSwitch();
    });});
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="pic" src="pool.jpg" />

<input type="range" id="red"  min="-255" max="255" value="0" />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code that you get source image data and change it indeed, but never draw it back. First, you need to define canvas as static tag instead of creating it on each change:

```
<canvas id="main"></canvas>
```

Second, in change callback get context from #main:

```
var canvas = $('#main')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Finally, after your pixel manipulations is done, draw changed bytes to #main:

```
ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0);
```

And one side-note: you don't need to create clone of image element, use existing since you don't modify it:

```
var photo = $('#pic')[0];
```